# How to show all the posts of America users if user is selected America ( In CharField Choices )

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I am Building a BlogApp and I am stuck on a Problem. I want to show all the Post of U.S.A if `request.user` is selected U.S.A in `CharField`

There's a one attribute named 'location' it have two choices 'America' and 'Australia'. I want it to shows only 'America Posts when user selects America'.

When user selects 'America' then I want to show the all posts of only users that are selected America.

if user selects 'Australia' then it finds all the users which are selected 'Australia' and show the posts of Australia users.

views.py

```
def showing_post(request,user_id):
    profiles = get_object_or_404(Profile,user_id=user_id)
    you = request.user

    shows = 'none'
    show = 'none'
    if profiles.location == 'America':
        show = Profile.objects.order_by('location')

    elif profiles.location == 'Australia':
        shows = Profile.objects.order_by('location')

    context = {'shows':shows,'show':show,'profiles':profiles}
    return render(request, 'opens.html', context)
```

opens.html

```
    {% if profiles.location == '-------' %}

        {% for p in show %}

        {{ p.location }}

        {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}
```

**The Problem**

When i check in the Page then it is showing all the users which selected the location of America and Australia, All are showing.

**What i am trying to do**

I want `if request.user select America then show only users that have selected America , AND don't show the users of Australia`.

**What have i tried**

I have also tried `location__icontains` but it didn't worked.

I don't know what i am doing wrong

Any help would be Appreciated

Thank You in Advance

Comment: You say "_user selects America_", but I don't see anything in your view that indicates that the User is selecting a location? It appears instead that they are selecting a Profile?

Comment: You're right. But how can i access model attribute's choice in view ? Please Help

Comment: Make `country` (best practice would be to name it as `COUNTRY_CHOICES` or something) a class attribute of your model. Now you can refer it as `Profile.country` (`Profile.COUNTRY_CHOICES`) in places you might need to. make a form and add a field to it which uses this choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am also new in django but you can try this.

views.py:

```
def showing_post(request,user_id):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,user_id=user_id)
    profile_location = Profile.objects.filter(location=profile.location)
    context = {'show':profile_location,'profile':profile}
    return render(request, 'opens.html', context)
```

opens.html:

```
 user:{{ profile.user }}
    location:{{ profile.location }}
      <h4>Users in {{ profile.location }}:</h4>
    {% for p in show %}
     
    {{ p.user }}

    {{ p.location }}

    {% empty %}
 <h4>No other users found in {{ profile.location }}</h3>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Instead of if-else `profile_location = Profile.objects.filter(location=profile.location)` would be much simpler. :)

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat thanks i have edited my answer.

Comment: What does `default='America' or 'Australia'` mean? or returns the first truthy value in this case it will return `'America'` so default is 'America' as you set.

Comment: Thanks You Very Much @amadousow and Abdul Aziz Barkat. It worked. Also it works fine in `location=India`. Thanks Again

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat. i just want to say that to default=' ' is not a good thing in Choices.it is always better to put a default='to one of the value in the choices'.